# How should I write this code?

Tags: java

```
    again:
        while (!s.hasNextInt()) s.next();
        amount = s.nextInt();
    if(amount < 0 || amount > numberOfCards) {
        System.out.println("You need to enter a number between 0 and "+numberOfCards);
        goto again; 
    }
```

It works fine in C# but in Java there is no goto. I can think of large complex ways of redoing this but I was interested in what is the cleanest most recommended way to write this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid way:

```
while (true) {
    while (!s.hasNextInt()) s.next();
        amount = s.nextInt();
    if(amount < 0 || amount > numberOfCards) {
        System.out.println("You need to enter a number between 0 and "+numberOfCards);
    } else {
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the smart way?

Comment: rewrite the code properly. stupid way == emulating goto (actually making "mandatory goto" aka `while (true)` and break to exit from this forever loop.

Comment: can you include the smart way in your answer like this Smart way:

Comment: again - rewrite the code so it'll not require goto. look at @Eran's answer (though it contain errors - as amount not initialized at first check) as example. `do {} while(...)` might help you. it's all up to you. though that "stupid" way is ok to have in production code. `break` is legal instruction. I called it stupid because there is better way to do your task.

Comment: You should include the best way you know of in your answer so future readers will know exactly what they should do.

Comment: best way is to implement code properly so it'll not require goto. come on.

Comment: I just don't understand how more code is better. In C# this code will work perfectly fine. It is a small little function... why would anyone be so brain dead over a little goto? I was just wondering what is the shortest way to reproduce this code because Eran's answer requires me to check the amount variable twice which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: shortest way - you have it already - see above :) some (not-so-smart) people consider goto bad for some unknown for me reason, so it's not present in some languages like java.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a loop :

```
while (amount < 0 || amount > numberOfCards) {
    while (!s.hasNextInt()) s.next();
    amount = s.nextInt();
    if(amount < 0 || amount > numberOfCards) {
        System.out.println("You need to enter a number between 0 and "+numberOfCards);
    }
}
```